# How to call a div link from another php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i am trying to call a page div from another php page.i call it using (found on net) admin.php#changepass

like----my html code

```
<div id="changepass" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <form name="changespass" class="w3-container" method="post" action="changepass.php">
   <h2 class="w3-text-blue">Change password</h2>
   <p>      
   <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Current Password</b></label>
   <input required autocomplete="off" name="currpass" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="password" style="width:30%">
    <p>      
   <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>New Password</b></label>
   <input required autocomplete="off" name="npass" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="password" style="width:30%">
    <p>    
    <p>      
   <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
   <input required  autocomplete="off" name="cpass" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="password" style="width:30%">
   <p>
   <button name="submitx" onclick="checkx()" class="w3-btn w3-cyan w3-border w3-border-red w3-round-xlarge">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and my php code from where i call it

```
                echo "<script>
                alert('vendors successfully added.');
                window.location.href='admin.php#changepass';
                </script>";
```

but it not working for me.it just show admin.php page 
can anybody help me.

Comment: once a request to a  new web page (URL) is made, that new URL has control over all functionality contained therein -- you cannot access divs from other different pages without fetching the content then loading it into your current page

Comment: how come @mike510a he can access .... he has to remove display:none that's it

Comment: @NishantSaini i must have misunderstood the question -- it wasnt very clear - sry

Comment: Which is the checkx() function?

Comment: @NishantSaini whats wrong with my question

Comment: @nayan nothing its ok

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="changepass" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

remove style="display:none"
```